# Row bind tables in SQL with differing columns

Tags: sql, r, join, union

I have a very simple request: I'd like to "stack" or vertically combine tables using SQL that share some column names, but not all column names.

If I were to attack this problem in R, Hadley Wickham's dplyr package has a nice function called `bind_rows()` that binds different tables by row, and coerces NA values when columns don't exist in one of the tables.

As an example, let's say we have table 'A':

```
a <- head(iris) %>% 
dplyr::mutate(., species_num = 1:nrow(.)) %>%
dplyr::select(., -Petal.Width)
```

[image]

And table 'B':

```
b <- tail(iris) %>%
dplyr::mutate(., species_num = 7:12)
```

[image]

Notice that table B has an extra column `Petal.Width`.

As I stated above, the R function `bind_rows()` in the dplyr package will do the following:

```
nice <- dplyr::bind_rows(a, b)
```

[image]

Pretty nice right?

Well, I want to perform this same action in SQL, but `UNION` fails when column number and/or names differ...

```
(SELECT *, FROM a)
UNION
(SELECT *, FROM b);
```

[image]

Now, I realize that I can simply add the `Petal.Width` column to table `a` before using `UNION`, but the real world issue I'm tackling involves over 30 tables that each contain some columns but not others in varying degrees...and my end goal is to automate this process. In short, I need a solution that will not require me to hack around the problem or add columns manually to individual tables.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the question you need to be asking is how to generate the query you need given a list of tables and their column names. That is, if you cannot work around the fact that SQL will not do what you want, you need to find a way to automate adding `,null as othername` for each name missing in a particular table.

Comment: In SQL you must list the columns in each Select in the same order and if a column is missing you must include it in the Select using `NULL AS "petal.width"`. Get the metadata for all tables, combine all column names into a unique list, left join this to each table and you got all columns and the missing columns are NULL. How to query metadata depends on your DBMS.

Comment: @r2evans - I like your answer. I'll look to detect missing columns for each table from a set of all possible column names given a priori. Then I can automate the addition of the missing columns for each table. Will post the result if/when I figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: it's `dplyr::bind_rows`, not in `dbplyr`.

Comment: @r2evans - I edited the question to read ```dplyr``` rather than ```dbplyr``` for ```bind_rows()```. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Prep with some fake data:

```
# con <- dbConnect(...)
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "iris1", iris[1:3,-1])
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "iris2", iris[4:6,-2])
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "iris23", iris[7:9,-(2:3)])
```

Set up the list of field names:

```
list_of_tables <- c("iris1", "iris2", "iris23")
eachnames <- sapply(list_of_tables, function(a) DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(con, DBI::dbListFields(con, a)), simplify = FALSE)
str(eachnames)
# List of 3
#  $ iris1 :Formal class 'SQL' [package "DBI"] with 1 slot
#   .. ..@ .Data: chr [1:4] "\"Sepal.Width\"" "\"Petal.Length\"" "\"Petal.Width\"" "\"Species\""
#  $ iris2 :Formal class 'SQL' [package "DBI"] with 1 slot
#   .. ..@ .Data: chr [1:4] "\"Sepal.Length\"" "\"Petal.Length\"" "\"Petal.Width\"" "\"Species\""
#  $ iris23:Formal class 'SQL' [package "DBI"] with 1 slot
#   .. ..@ .Data: chr [1:3] "\"Sepal.Length\"" "\"Petal.Width\"" "\"Species\""
allnames <- unique(unlist(eachnames, use.names=FALSE))
allnames
# [1] "\"Sepal.Width\""  "\"Petal.Length\"" "\"Petal.Width\""  "\"Species\""     
# [5] "\"Sepal.Length\""
```

I used `DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier` to be a little defensive in general, though it is specifically required due to column names (I'm using postgres which doesn't like an unescaped period in the field name).

The list of field names, augmented with `null as`, can be made with this:

```
list_of_fields <- lapply(eachnames, function(a) {
  paste(ifelse(allnames %in% a, allnames, paste("null as", allnames)), collapse = ", ")
})
str(list_of_fields)
# List of 3
#  $ iris1 : chr "\"Sepal.Width\", \"Petal.Length\", \"Petal.Width\", \"Species\", null as \"Sepal.Length\""
#  $ iris2 : chr "null as \"Sepal.Width\", \"Petal.Length\", \"Petal.Width\", \"Species\", \"Sepal.Length\""
#  $ iris23: chr "null as \"Sepal.Width\", null as \"Petal.Length\", \"Petal.Width\", \"Species\", \"Sepal.Length\""
```

If you have more complex query needs, then that's a good start. Here's a query that does no additional filtering:

```
qry <- paste(
  mapply(function(nm, flds) {
    paste("( select",
          paste(ifelse(allnames %in% flds, allnames, paste("null as", allnames)),
                collapse = ", "),
          "from", nm, ")")
  }, names(eachnames), eachnames),
  collapse = " union\n")
cat(qry)
# ( select "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species", null as "Sepal.Length" from iris1 ) union
# ( select null as "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species", "Sepal.Length" from iris2 ) union
# ( select null as "Sepal.Width", null as "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species", "Sepal.Length" from iris23 )
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, qry)
#   Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length
# 1          NA          1.7         0.4  setosa          5.4
# 2          NA           NA         0.3  setosa          4.6
# 3          NA          1.5         0.2  setosa          4.6
# 4          NA          1.4         0.2  setosa          5.0
# 5         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa           NA
# 6         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa           NA
# 7          NA           NA         0.2  setosa          5.0
# 8          NA           NA         0.2  setosa          4.4
# 9         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa           NA
```

Many DBAs will advise against using `SELECT *` in general, so this has a secondary benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with the answers provided by @r2evans earlier today to come up with the following, which works for my real world situation (for reproducibility, see @r2evans' very detailed answer). I'm sure the apply approach is more efficient than looping, but this was my start.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(myTables)) {

  # Load drivers
  drv <- RPostgreSQL::postgresqlInitDriver()

  # Establish connection to the database
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(drv, host=creds[1], port=creds[2], dbname=creds[3], 
                        user=creds[4], password=creds[5])

  # Return column names and variable class
  tableColumns <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT column_name, data_type ",
                                          "FROM   information_schema.columns ",
                                          "WHERE  table_name = '", 
                                           myTables[i,'table_name'], "' ",
                                          "ORDER  BY ordinal_position"))

  # Close out the database connection
  DBI::dbDisconnect(con)

  # Determine missing columnms
  colDiffs <- setdiff(desiredCols, tableColumns$column_name)


  if(length(colDiffs) > 0) {

    # Create SQL subqueries, complete with inclusion for missing columns
    myTables[i,'subquery'] <- paste0('(SELECT *, ',
                                      paste(paste0('NULL AS ', colDiffs, ', '), 
                                                    collapse = ''), "'",
                                      myTables[i,'table_name'], "' AS table ",
                                      "FROM schema.", myTables[i,'table_name'], 
                                      ")")

  } else {

    # Create SQL subqueries
    myTables[i,'subquery'] <- paste0("(SELECT *, '",
                                       myTables[i,'table_name'], "' AS table ",
                                      "FROM schema.", myTables[i,'table_name'], ")")
  }

}


# Create final query
finalQuery <- paste(myTables$subquery, collapse=" UNION ")
```

Comment: @r2evans - you definitely have the accepted answer. I'm planning to roll in your approach today! Thanks again.